require doesn't work on folders containing "init.lua"
Minimal Config
init.lua
require("lua") --or require("lua.init")

lua/init.lua
print("Hello World")

Expected Behavior
"Hello World" get's printed on nvim startup
Actual Behavior
If I'm not in my config folder, An error message saying it can't find module "lua" in some random lua folders including ./ which is why it works if you're in the config folder.

or


Please don't share screenshots of error messages or output. Instead, put the errors in your question, in a code section. Thank you.

Welcome to [vi.se]! It's unclear to me whether lua/init.lua is in your home directory (which might be current directory) or on another directory, possibly your config under ~/.config/nvim. When I use require("lua.init") it seems to work for me, it finds lua/init.lua as expected. Your usage of "lua" (instead of something like "trythis" or "testing" etc.) makes this a little hard to follow too, I suggest retesting with a different unique name and updating the post. Also, take a look at :lua =package.path which shows where Neovim will look for Lua modules.

Re :lua =package.path, on my system Neovim does include ./?.lua which would make require("lua") look for ./lua.lua but it does not include ./?/init.lua which would match ./lua/init.lua

The root for lua importation in Neovim is already lua.
Something somehow equivalent of what you want to do would be:
nvim/init.lua:
require("foo")

nvim/lua/foo/init.lua:
print("Hello World")

You notice that the root lua is not explicitly needed in init.lua like if the root of init.lua would already be nvim/lua/
